# Seeding a user supplied random number generator in R

Tags: r, random, r-extension

I'm having some trouble with seeding a user defined RNG in R. It seems that

```
set.seed(123, kind='user', normal.kind='user')
```

Does not actually pass `123` to the user defined RNG initialization.

I went back to the documentation available at `?Random.user` and tried the example code given there, with the minor modification that I print the seed passed to the `user_unif_init` function (full code below).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Paste code below in `urand.c`
2. Run `R CMD SHLIB urand.c`
3. Open `R`
4. Run the following commands:

   ```
   > dyn.load('urand.so')
   > set.seed(123, kind='user', normal.kind='user')
   Received seed: 720453763
   Received seed: 303482705 // any other numbers than 123
   ```

Here's the full code I used in `urand.c`:

```
// ##  Marsaglia's congruential PRNG

#include <stdio.h>
#include <R_ext/Random.h>

static Int32 seed;
static double res;
static int nseed = 1;

double * user_unif_rand()
{
    seed = 69069 * seed + 1;
    res = seed * 2.32830643653869e-10;
    return &res;
}

void  user_unif_init(Int32 seed_in) {
    printf("Received seed: %u\n", seed_in);
    seed = seed_in;
}
int * user_unif_nseed() { return &nseed; }
int * user_unif_seedloc() { return (int *) &seed; }

/*  ratio-of-uniforms for normal  */
#include <math.h>
static double x;

double * user_norm_rand()
{
    double u, v, z;
    do {
        u = unif_rand();
        v = 0.857764 * (2. * unif_rand() - 1);
        x = v/u; z = 0.25 * x * x;
        if (z < 1. - u) break;
        if (z > 0.259/u + 0.35) continue;
    } while (z > -log(u));
    return &x;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that R scrambles the user supplied seed in `RNG.c` as follows:

```
for(j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    seed = (69069 * seed + 1)
```

([link to source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/452e284fe7c76ee25f5cac36614f79758546c051/src/main/RNG.c#L266))

Trying to unscramble this would be a way to get the original seed back.

**UPDATE**

Unscrambling can be done through the [multiplicative inverse](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250811/undoing-an-integer-wraparound/250820) of 69069 as follows:

```
Int32 unscramble(Int32 scrambled)
{
        int j;
        Int32 u = scrambled;
        for (j=0; j<50; j++) {
                u = ((u - 1) * 2783094533);
        }
        return u;
}
```

Plugging this in my `user_unif_init()` function solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The seed that is forwarded to the RNG is different from the provided seed, however, it is reproducible when a "normal" workflow is used. This then gives reproducible random numbers:

```r
dyn.load('urand.so')
RNGkind("user", "user")
#> Received seed: 1844983443
set.seed(123)
#> Received seed: 303482705
runif(10)
#>  [1] 0.42061954 0.77097033 0.14981063 0.27065365 0.77665767 0.96882090
#>  [7] 0.49077135 0.08621131 0.52903479 0.90398294
set.seed(123)
#> Received seed: 303482705
runif(10)
#>  [1] 0.42061954 0.77097033 0.14981063 0.27065365 0.77665767 0.96882090
#>  [7] 0.49077135 0.08621131 0.52903479 0.90398294
```

(Note that I have changed your `urand.c` slightly to use `Rprintf` from `R_ext/Print.h`.)

---

Edit: If you need control over the seed (why?), than you can do it yourself: replace `user_unif_init`, `user_unif_nseed` and `user_unif_seedloc` with

```r
void set_seed(int * seed_in) {
    Rprintf("Received seed: %u\n", *seed_in);
    seed = *seed_in;
}
```

And call it explicitly:

```r
dyn.load('urand.so')
RNGkind("user", "user")
set_seed <- function(seed) {
  invisible(.C("set_seed", seed_in = as.integer(seed)))
}
set_seed(123)
#> Received seed: 123
runif(10)
#>  [1] 0.00197801 0.61916849 0.34846373 0.04152509 0.09669026 0.29923760
#>  [7] 0.04184693 0.32557942 0.44473242 0.22339845
set_seed(123)
#> Received seed: 123
runif(10)
#>  [1] 0.00197801 0.61916849 0.34846373 0.04152509 0.09669026 0.29923760
#>  [7] 0.04184693 0.32557942 0.44473242 0.22339845
```

---

Edit 2: Have alook into the source at https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/RNG.c:

```r
static void RNG_Init(RNGtype kind, Int32 seed)
{
    int j;

    BM_norm_keep = 0.0; /* zap Box-Muller history */

    /* Initial scrambling */
    for(j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    seed = (69069 * seed + 1);
    [...]
```

These 50 LCG rounds are responsible for the difference. My guess is that the authors of R assume that typical user supplied seeds are small and are therefore not random enough for a seed.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! It's nice to know that it's consistent, but this doesn't really solve my problem. I need to be able to get ``123`` in the C function. Is there any way to bypass or undo the black magic that R inserts into this seemingly straighforward process?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I need control over the seed for a specific application. Your solution is a nice work-around, but it doesn't quite answer my question. I wonder what R is doing to the seed and for what purpose it would be useful.